# How to edit an R markdown YAML header programmatically?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Take for example this Rmd file - https://github.com/rstudio/learnr/blob/master/inst/tutorials/ex-setup-r/ex-setup-r.Rmd

The YAML header has this -

```
output:
  learnr::tutorial:
    progressive: true
    allow_skip: true
```

I would like to change this to -

```
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    widescreen: true
```

Is there a way to make this edit programmatically i.e. Can I write some function that takes an Rmd file as input, edits the YAML header, and produces a new Rmd file?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide more information? You can of course read in the lines of a .Rmd file and then parse the header (using line breaks, colons, etc) and replace certain elements. Do you always want that first header to become the second header? Is there any logic for how to go from the first to the second?

Comment: You can create your own [rmarkdown template](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/document-templates.html) with the desired output type (and any other desired features and settings) as the default. If you really do want to programmatically edit the yaml of an existing file, then [this Rstudio Community post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-can-i-read-parse-the-metadata-from-an-rmarkdown-file/47886/8?u=joels) might be helpful.

Comment: See package ymlthis: https://github.com/r-lib/ymlthis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a quick function could do this.

```r
change_yaml_matter <- function(input_file, ..., output_file) {
  input_lines <- readLines(input_file)
  delimiters <- grep("^---\\s*$", input_lines)
  if (!length(delimiters)) {
    stop("unable to find yaml delimiters")
  } else if (length(delimiters) == 1L) {
    if (delimiters[1] == 1L) {
      stop("cannot find second delimiter, first is on line 1")
    } else {
      # found just one set, assume it is *closing* the yaml matter;
      # fake a preceding line of delimiter
      delimiters <- c(0L, delimiters[1])
    }
  }
  delimiters <- delimiters[1:2]
  yaml_list <- yaml::yaml.load(input_lines[ (delimiters[1]+1):(delimiters[2]-1) ])

  dots <- list(...)
  yaml_list <- c(yaml_list[ setdiff(names(yaml_list), names(dots)) ], dots)

  output_lines <- c(
    if (delimiters[1] > 0) input_lines[1:(delimiters[1])],
    strsplit(yaml::as.yaml(yaml_list), "\n")[[1]],
    input_lines[ -(1:(delimiters[2]-1)) ]
  )

  if (missing(output_file)) {
    return(output_lines)
  } else {
    writeLines(output_lines, con = output_file)
    return(invisible(output_lines))
  }
}
```

Where `...` is *whatever you want it to be*. Meaning: if you want to replace the `output:` component of the yaml matter, then you give a named list as `output=list(...)`.

If I use the rmarkdown document I used in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62095301/3358272), then *unchanged*, it looks like this:

```r
readLines("~/StackOverflow/1883604/62095186.Rmd")
#  [1] "---"                                              
#  [2] "title: Hello"                                     
#  [3] "output: html_document"                            
#  [4] "params:"                                          
#  [5] "  intab: TRUE"                                    
#  [6] "---"                                              
#  [7] ""                                                 
#  [8] "# Headline 1"                                     
#  [9] ""                                                 
# [10] "## Headline 2 `r if (params$intab) \"{.tabset}\"`"
# [11] ""                                                 
# [12] "### Headline 3 in a tab"                          
# [13] ""                                                 
# [14] "### Headline 4 in a tab"                          
# [15] ""                                                 
# [16] "### Headline 5 in a tab"                          
# [17] ""                                                 
# [18] ""
```

And to change the `output` portion, I add a nested named list as:

```r
change_yaml_matter("~/StackOverflow/1883604/62095186.Rmd", 
                   output=list(ioslides_presentation=list(widescreen=TRUE)))
#  [1] "---"                                              
#  [2] "title: Hello"                                     
#  [3] "params:"                                          
#  [4] "  intab: yes"                                     
#  [5] "output:"                                          
#  [6] "  ioslides_presentation:"                         
#  [7] "    widescreen: yes"                              
#  [8] "---"                                              
#  [9] ""                                                 
# [10] "# Headline 1"                                     
# [11] ""                                                 
# [12] "## Headline 2 `r if (params$intab) \"{.tabset}\"`"
# [13] ""                                                 
# [14] "### Headline 3 in a tab"                          
# [15] ""                                                 
# [16] "### Headline 4 in a tab"                          
# [17] ""                                                 
# [18] "### Headline 5 in a tab"                          
# [19] ""                                                 
# [20] ""
```

You can change just about any portion of the yaml matter. (The only things you cannot change, I suspect, are if you happen to have yaml parameters named `input_file` or `output_file`. If you actually have Rmd files with those yaml top-level parameters, then you can easily rename the named arguments here to be something else, such as [`Mxyzptlk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mister_Mxyzptlk) and something else ... you're unlikely to see those in production.)

Notes:

- This did not save anything to a file, you have to do that yourself. Add `output_file="path/to/new.RMd"` to your call, and it will write a new file.
- When you do include `output_file=` in the arguments, if you choose to not catch the return value, it will *appear* to return nothing. This is due to `invisible` in my return; if you really want to see and save, either capture to a variable and look at that, or wrap the function call in parens, as in `(change_yaml_matter(...))`.

The trick for YAML is to know that `yaml::` will treat every top-level as the named element of a list, and its contents are recursively lists in the same manner. For instance,

```r
str(yaml::yaml.load("
---
top1:
  level2a:
    level3a: 123
    level3b: 456
  level2b: 789
top2: quux
---"))
# List of 2
#  $ top1:List of 2
#   ..$ level2a:List of 2
#   .. ..$ level3a: int 123
#   .. ..$ level3b: int 456
#   ..$ level2b: int 789
#  $ top2: chr "quux"
```

To assign new values, just provide nested named lists.

Comment: r2evans - Thank you!! This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thanks for taking the time to provide a thorough response.

Answer (score 1):

I modified it slightly.

With the version given, if an existing yaml element is changed, it is moved to the end of the yaml header.

With my modification, existing elements with changed values will keep their position in the header.

```
change_yaml_matter <- function(input_file, ..., output_file) {
  input_lines <- readLines(input_file)
  delimiters <- grep("^---\\s*$", input_lines)
  if (!length(delimiters)) {
    stop("unable to find yaml delimiters")
  } else if (length(delimiters) == 1L) {
    if (delimiters[1] == 1L) {
      stop("cannot find second delimiter, first is on line 1")
    } else {
      # found just one set, assume it is *closing* the yaml matter;
      # fake a preceding line of delimiter
      delimiters <- c(0L, delimiters[1])
    }
  }
  delimiters <- delimiters[1:2]
  yaml_list <- yaml::yaml.load(
    input_lines[ (delimiters[1]+1):(delimiters[2]-1) ])

  dots <- list(...)
    
  for (element_name in names(dots)){
    if(element_name %in% names(yaml_list)) {
      yaml_list[element_name] <- dots[element_name]
    } else {
      yaml_list <- c(yaml_list,dots[element_name]) 
    }
  }
    
  output_lines <- c(
    if (delimiters[1] > 0) input_lines[1:(delimiters[1])],
    strsplit(yaml::as.yaml(yaml_list), "\n")[[1]],
    input_lines[ -(1:(delimiters[2]-1)) ]
  )

  if (missing(output_file)) {
    return(output_lines)
  } else {
    writeLines(output_lines, con = output_file)
    return(invisible(output_lines))
  }
}
```