# Programmatically add tags to yaml header during knitting R markdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, blogdown

I'd like to programmatically add tags to the YAML header of a blogdown post when clicking the "knit" button.

For example something like this:

```
---
title: This is a post
author: brshallo
date: '2022-02-11'
tags: "`r stringr::str_c('\n  - ', stringr::str_flatten(c('rstats', 'datascience'), '\n  - '))`"
slug: this-is-a-post
---
```

#### Related Resources

I've tried a variety of solutions with `!r`, `!expr`,
and iterations on these but so far no luck.

Here are some related threads:

- [Importing common YAML in rstudio/knitr document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885363/importing-common-yaml-in-rstudio-knitr-document)
- [How to edit an R markdown YAML header programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62095329/how-to-edit-an-r-markdown-yaml-header-programmatically)
- https://community.rstudio.com/t/is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-nested-group-of-params-in-rmarkdown-yaml-if-not-should-there-be/117393/2
- https://community.rstudio.com/t/rmarkdown-list-in-yaml/94147/5
- packages: [ymlthis](https://github.com/r-lib/ymlthis) and [yaml](https://github.com/vubiostat/r-yaml/)
- context: [blogdown#647](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/647)

I'd at first assumed this was a more general rmarkdown problem rather than blogdown specific but given that some of the solutions mentioned in threads above seemed to work when inputting generic params I wasn't sure...

Comment: This was explained in https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/647#issuecomment-1041599327. Please feel free to answer your own question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate a valid YAML array, you could use the alternative syntax [ ], e.g.,

```
tags: ["`r paste(head(letters), collapse = '", "')`"]
```

which generates:

```
tags: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

Note the hack `collapse = '", "'`: since there already exists a pair of double quotes outside the R expression, you should only generate the part `a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f` from the R expression.

-- solution copied from Yihui's explanation at [blogdown#647](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/647#issuecomment-1041599327)

Comment: is there a way to generate `params:` programatically in the same fashion? It would be nice to create params dynamically based on my R Shiny input controls, instead of manually adding them everytime. Can be cumbersome when dealing with hundreds of parameters.